# Angular controller is not working after including ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

This is my ngRoute (AngularApp.js)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$routeProvider.
    when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/AdminPage/register.html', controller: 'registerCtrl'}).
    when('/updateEmployee', {templateUrl: 'partials/AdminPage/updateEmployee.html', controller: 'updateEmployeeCtrl'}).
    when('/designers',{templateUrl: 'partials/CreateSurvey/design.html',controller: 'DesignCtrl'});

});
```

This is Another js file where my other controllers are (AngularApp2.js)`

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myController',function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){

        $scope.myData = response;
    });
    $scope.removeName = function(row) {
        $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(row),1);
    }
});
```

But when I include both angular code in one file as below, the 'myController' is not working.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$routeProvider.
    when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/AdminPage/register.html', controller: 'registerCtrl'}).
    when('/updateEmployee', {templateUrl: 'partials/AdminPage/updateEmployee.html', controller: 'updateEmployeeCtrl'}).
    when('/designers',{templateUrl: 'partials/CreateSurvey/design.html',controller: 'DesignCtrl'});

});

app.controller('myController',function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){

        $scope.myData = response;
    });
    $scope.removeName = function(row) {
        $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(row),1);
    }
});
```

What is the error I am making?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you refer the angular route scripts?

Comment: Nothing happens. all the controllers below are not working when I include the ngRoute. My be I am not writing the code properly.

Comment: which name are you actually using in `ng-app`?

Comment: @K.Kabilesh Check my sample attached in the answer

Comment: @K.Kabilesh did you sort out the issue?

Comment: Yes. I added the code in two different files with same module name. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 different modules `app` and `myApp` but never inject one as dependency of the other

Assuming your `ng-app` uses `app` as main module you need to inject the `myApp` module into `app` one, or make both names the same so you only have one module

Comment: sure..as long as your main module name is the one in `ng-app` which still isn't clear. Also not clear if you wanted 2 modules or you misspelled one...can do it either way

Comment: I wanted to write all angular in one file. But because of the ngRoute code the controllers written for other tasks are not working. If I delete the ngRoute or if put them in different files everything is fine. This is the problem.

Comment: something else wrong, number of files is not relevant. Might be loading order. Are you even looking for errors in browser console?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you have

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

it shoud be

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Also make sure you use the `ng-app="app"` in the HTML if you are declaring as first way.

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pIKB6Gz8t7a49yW3PA29?p=preview)**